How to make letters look like in the same row in tabular
I am making a tabular with 2 columns, the first is Japanese and the second one is English. But when converting to pdf they look like not in the same row, help me pleaseee!



Welcome. // Please copy your code from the screenshot directly, so we can copy and try it (at least the members who work with Asian languages). Thank you

For one thing, you columns are too wide.  There is an extra 4\tabcolsep which is added by tabular.  The real question is where is the baseline relative to the text?  You can use \hfill\llap{\rule{\hsize}{0.5pt}} at the end of each line on each side to show the baseline location.

Your main language is English, so you don't need \selectlanguage{english}. In any case, it should be \foreignlanguage{english}{Monkey}.
